# How to switch between Gnome & Mate desktops?

Tags: mate

When I reinstalled OS, I had only one -- Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome desktop -- option. I got used to Mate desktop. Therefore, I installed Mate desktop too. Having two desktops -- Mate & Gnome -- how to switch between them? I cannot just remove Gnome as it affects Libre Office. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you really don't need GNOME and want to save some disk space, consider installing Ubuntu MATE

Comment: How did you install mate-desktop? Maybe you did not install all the packages. Please provide more details.

Comment: That I did as is written in my question. Mate is there but sort of shut up by Gnome.

Comment: And, far as I remember, the installation was full.

Comment: What command did you use to install mate desktop?

Comment: I don't remember that command. Maybe it was the correct one, maybe not. But I definitely didn't concoct any, just picked it up from AskUbuntu. Anyhow, what can I command now?

Comment: Try reinstalling MATE with `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Comment: Done, the same Gnome is back. Probably I have to make the Ubuntu-Mate installation tool and reinstall again.

Answer (score 0):

On your login screen you should see a sign that looks like a gear. Clicking on that should give you the choice between Gnome and Mate.

For example, this is such an image of the login screen showing the gear icon.

[image]

(Image source: https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/archive/42.3/gnomeuser/html/book.gnomeuser/cha.gnomeuser.start.html)

Comment: I should but I don't. On the screen, I have Activities, Applications, Power switch, date & time, Livepatch, Internet, and sound. I tried logging out & back on but got nowhere.

Comment: I don't have that good picture.